# SubSonic Outer Join

Tags: linq, subsonic, subsonic3, outer-join

There seems to be a Bug with the Outer Join statement in SubSonic 3, or maybe it's just my ignorance, but the following craps out:

```
var Objeto = from t in Table1.All()
             join su in table2.All() on t.Id equals su.Id
             join tab2 in Table1.All() on t.PId equals tab2.Id into gj
             from j in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 t.Field1,
                 SN = su.Field123,
                 PTN = (j == null ? null : j.FieldABC)
              };
```

**With:**

```
The expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable` xxxx is not a sequence
```

Comment: If I remove the outer join it works perfectly.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They already had issues with IQueryable:

[Blog Entry](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-3-0-iqueryable-update/)

Just for your Information...

Comment: dude, this is a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: yeah true...i am still looking for an solution. So the Blog Entry is a good starting point...

Comment: For now the answer seems to be that this is a bug in SubSonic.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving an old topic here, but for those that come searching along later, there is a different syntax that seems to work correctly in SubSonic3 for a left outer join.

Instead of the Linq expression from the original post that does a `join ... into ...`
Rewrite it to:

```
var Objeto = from t in Table1.All()
         join su in table2.All() on t.Id equals su.Id
         from j in Table1.All().Where(x => x.Id == t.PId).DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             t.Field1,
             SN = su.Field123,
             PTN = (j == null ? null : j.FieldABC)
          };
```

The key part being: `from j in Table1.All().Where(x => x.Id == t.PId).DefaultIfEmpty()` which will do the outer join, instead of the traditional `join ... into`

Hopefully this helps!